# Find $[Q(w,√3) :Q] $ and find a basis

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $w∈\mathbb C$ be a root of the polynomial $X^4−12$. Determine $[Q(w,√3) :Q]$ and give a basis of $Q(w,√3)$ over $Q$. [You may express the elements of your basis in terms of w. Note that the exact value of w is not given.]

$$
\begin{matrix}
&  & \mathbb Q(w, \sqrt{3}) &  & \\
& \stackrel{a}{\diagup} & & \stackrel{b}{\diagdown} \\
\mathbb Q(w) & & & & \mathbb Q(\sqrt{3}) \\
& \stackrel{c}{\diagdown} & & \stackrel{d}{\diagup} \\
& & \mathbb Q
\end{matrix}
$$

---

$d=2$ clearly, easy to prove so this implies $a \le 2$

$c=4$ because $X^4-12$ is the minimum polynomial of $Q(w)$ over $Q$. Irreducibility is checked by Eisenstein with $p=3$.

So $[Q(w,√3) :Q]\le 8$. And $a=1$ since $Q(w,\sqrt3) =Q(w)$ (i can prove this) and $[Q(w,√3) :Q]=4$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $ X^4 - 12 = (X^2 - 2 \sqrt{3})(X^2 + 2\sqrt{3}) $ so that the minimal polynomial of $ w $ over $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) $ is of degree 2. This tells you that $ [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, w) : \mathbb{Q}] = 4 $. A basis can be given by $ \{ 1, \sqrt{3}, w, w\sqrt{3} \} $.

Alternatively, you can note that $ \mathbb{Q}(w) $ already contains $ \sqrt{3} $, so $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, w) = \mathbb{Q}(w) $, in which case finding the basis is straightforward: $ \{1, w, w^2, w^3\} $.

Comment: Hang on, i think i got my degree value wrong didn't i? $Q(w,\sqrt3)$ IS equal to $Q(w)$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is, since $ w^2 = \pm 2\sqrt{3} $.

Comment: Is my working out for the degree fine though?

Comment: There is no "working out for the degree", it follows immediately when you see that $ \mathbb{Q}(w, \sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(w) $ and that $ X^4 - 12 $ is irreducible in $ \mathbb{Q}[X] $.

Comment: oh i see. What an easy question...